# Unity app uses far more memory on IOS than on Android

Tags: android, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, memory

I've build an app in unity for both android and IOS, and android has been running perfectly fine for months now. But IOS devices crash on a ram overflow error (EXC_RESOURCE RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY (limit=1450 MB, unused=0x0) on Iphone 7).

I've since reduced all the texture sizes (some were like 8k so this was a significant reduction) and I also compressed all the audio files. This got it working locally, but I've been rejected from the app store for crashing their test device (an Ipad).

I've never had any issues with Android, even on older devices with the uncompressed textures and audio, so why do these issues occur on IOS devices with far less memory usage?

Answer (score 1):

Compression works very differently on Android and iOS.

This is a common problem with iOS, i myself have battled with it for years.

Try the following:

1. In order for your images to be properly compressed on apple platforms, they must be power of 2. On android this is not the case.
2. Manage all your images and audio files with the unity [addressable asset system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.4/manual/index.html) and load them into memory when required instead of having them in memory all the time.
3. Use sprite atlases
4. Check your audio file import settings, this is a common gotcha.
5. You mentioned that some images used to be 8k! That's crazy big. Even 4K or 1080 is unnecessary in my opinion. Try setting the maximum size of each image down to very small and slowly increase until you are happy with the way it looks. I bet you will be very surprised by how small you can get away with.

Number 5 is your best bet and a very important thing to learn.

And so number 2 is important to know about. If it seems complicated and too much work, then make games with less assets in them, because memory management is inescapable in larger games.

Comment: Hi, first off, thanks for your feedback. this same question has been ignored before. I've tried method 5 and reduced all my textures to 512 with 256 for normal maps etc. I also reduced audio and mesh quite a bit. But the problem remains. The difference with android is what baffles me and makes me think i must be missing something that causes this insane ram usage. The problem occurs when loading in the scriptable objects which contain the audio files and animations (meshes etc,) Is it possible to switch to regular storage instead of ram or something? Anyways, ill deffo have a look @ the sugges

Comment: yeah checkout point 2 from my answer, that will allow you to store things in storage and load them to memory when you need them. Unfortunately the way ram works in iOS is fundamentally different to android, you can't really compare them both.

Comment: also, learn to use the unity profiler, then you don't have to guess where the memory is being taken up, it will just tell you what exactly is happening

Comment: Yes, I've known about the profiler for a while but this issue has forced me to really start using it now. It hasn't helped me much in this case but its definetly best practice to use it. Tip number 2 is the one I expect will fix my issue, and I will definetly look into it. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking the same thing, but if you look at the difference in RAM performance between Android and iPhone devices, you'll probably be convinced. Android devices generally have much more RAM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).